# Changing UI router state by updating location.path when base href is present

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

The app I am working have a base href

```
<base href="/xyz/">
```

and the state config looks similar to

```
.state('state1', {
        url: '/abc/:def/:ghi',
        views: 'view1',
    })
    .state('state2', {
   url:'/abc/:def/:ghi/jk/:123/:456',
        views: 'view2',
    })
```

and to get the current URL I am doing

```
var browserUrl = $state.href($state.current.name, $state.params, { absolute: false });
```

this return me

```
/xyz/abc/:def/:ghi
```

I don't have a problem when I do $state.go to goto state2 but if I use $location.path to update the URL then UI router is unable to match the state since the base href is present in the newUrl. To update the state I am doing

```
var 123Id = 'item1'                                                               
var 456Id = 'item2'
var newUrl = [browserUrl, 'jk', 123Id, 456Id].join('/');
$location.path(newUrl)
```

this is not working since the browesrUrl contains the base href, any idea how to make this working by updating the location ?

Comment: Why is `browserUrl` containing the full browserUrl? Could you please add the output of `browserUrl` which is parsed into your `join()` function?

Comment: @lin it has base href in it because I am using $state.href to dynamically generate the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy workaround would be to use `$location.url()`instead of `$location.path()`. `url()` is able to handle absolute URLs in that way you could generate a absolute URL like:

```
var browserUrl = $state.href($state.current.name, $state.params, { absolute: true });
$location.url(browserUrl);
```

Comment: instead of  doing $state.href($state.current.name, $state.params, { absolute: true }); using $location.path() resolved my issue. But I have tested your solution and it worked too

Comment: @Venkat glad to help ya.I'm wondering that it works with `$location.path()` too because it's documented in a different way "A path should start with an `/`"...